# Error when loading mobx-react as UMD from a CDN

Tags: javascript, mobx, mobx-react

Since version `6.0.0`, loading `mobx-react` as UMD from a CDN causes an error. Is there a solution to this?

**Example**

```js
const { observer } = mobxReact;

const App = observer(() => <div>Example</div>);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mobx@6.0.4/dist/mobx.umd.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mobx-react@7.0.5/dist/mobxreact.umd.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since version `6.0.0`, `mobx-react` depends on the `mobx-react-lite` package which it uses on function components when using `observer`.

If you are only using function components in your app you can use `mobx-react-lite` directly if you prefer, which is slightly faster and smaller (only 1.5kB gzipped).

**Example**

```js
const { observer } = mobxReact;

const App = observer(() => <div>Example</div>);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mobx@6.0.4/dist/mobx.umd.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mobx-react-lite@3.1.6/dist/mobxreactlite.umd.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mobx-react@7.0.5/dist/mobxreact.umd.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```